How many unique circuits can be made given n equal resistors?
Really stumped by this one (I'm not an EE!). Suppose we are given $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, and $6$ one-ohm resistors. They can be arranged in series, parallel, bridge, and so forth circuits. No dangling resistors allowed, nor short circuits. $1$. So, given one resistor, we can wire one unique circuit. For $2$ we can wire $2$ circuits. For three we can wire $4$ circuits. But for $4$, how many? For $5$, how many? For $6$, how many? $2$. How about if up to and including $2$ (we get $3$ there), up to and including $3$ (we get $7$ there), ..., up and including $6$ resistors? Is there some general way to do these calculations for, say, $n$ resistors? I see that maybe part of the answer (for $1$.) can be found looking at OEIS A174283, but not sure how to do the rest of it ($2$.).

Related: Combinations of resistor networks?, Given
identical resistors
, find combinations of series, parallel, and series-parallel arrangements.

What constitutes a unique circuit? I assume you mean unique up to circuit topology without simplification, but there may be a few interesting ways to do it. Unique up to equivalent resistance between two nodes seems like it could be fun too.

Do you also have a single power source (and do you care about its direction), or are you just hooking resistors together into an inert circuit?

I meant to say unique overall values of resistance.

https://doi.org/10.1119/1.19396
